# In Hugo/blogdown academic theme: How does one show full lists of posts, publications, and talks?

Tags: r, yaml, blogdown, hugo-theme, wowchemy

How does one display the whole list of publications, talks, etc. shown in the latest yaml based hugo/blogdown academic-theme? instead of default = abbreviated list of five publications with a link to "show all publications".

In earlier versions there used to be a `config.toml` or `posts.md` file, in which the count could be increased. Now there only is a an `\website_new\content\publication\index.md` file in which `view` may be increased, however this did not change anything. The list is still abbreviated.

Do I need to [create](https://github.com/koenraadvanmeerbeek/Website/blob/master/content/home/publications.md?plain=1) a `pubications.md`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to open `...\website\content\_index.md` and each block has a `content`field. There one need to insert `count: 100` below this to e.g. show 100 publications as explained [here](https://github.com/HugoBlox/hugo-blox-builder/issues/181)